# '86^M^\^M', what is M sign in this string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In rails, I place some integer like 86value in cache(redis), but it appears to be "'86^M^\^M'" when reading from redis.
What is ^M sign stand for? I've never seen it before.

Answer (score 2):

`^M` sign you see is not specifically related to redis. In general it signifies new line. Here's the detail:

> The ^M is a carriage-return character. If you see this, you're
>   probably looking at a file that originated in the DOS/Windows world,
>   where an end-of-line is marked by a carriage return/newline pair,
>   whereas in the Unix world, end-of-line is marked by a single newline.

For more details: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32001/what-is-m-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it